# React, passing a function in props is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to delete a certain entry in my list according to its index. However, the delete button is in a separate component. So I need to pass the function that deletes the entry in the list from my current app component to the child content component.

The App.js is:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Content from './components/Content/Content';

function App() {

  const Tours = [
    {
      image: "",
      title: "",
      price: "$",
      text: ""
    }
  ]

  const [list, setList] = useState(Tours);

  function handleRemove(id) {
    console.log(id)
    const newList = list.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setList(newList);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((value, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <Content tour={value} delete={ () => handleRemove(index)}/>
          </div>)
        })
      }
    </div>    
  );
}

export default App;
```

component.js is:

```
const Content = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="single-tour">
      <img src = {props.tour.image} alt= {props.tour.title}></img>
      <div className="container">
        <h4 className ="title">{props.tour.title}</h4>
        <h4 className="tour-price">{props.tour.price}</h4>
        <button className="delete-btn" onClick={()=> props.delete}>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};
  
export default Content;
```

the console.log in the handleDelete is not showing, meaning the function is not being passed. What is the problem?

Comment: in the child component can you just try ```onClick={props.delete}``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
onClick={()=> props.delete()}
```

or

```
onClick={props.delete}
```

In order to remove the card according to the `id` values, please also add them to your `Tours` object:

```
const Tours = [
    {
      image: "",
      title: "",
      price: "$",
      text: "",
      id: 1,
    }
  ]
```

Comment: ok the console.log(id) is working now but the entry is still not deleted from the list. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: you are doing ```list.filter((item) => item.id !== id);``` but the object in ```Tours``` array dont have an id property

Comment: Marc is completely right and I added his comment to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the value to the function like this.

here is the codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-func-props-j6idr?file=/src/index.js

you should and id field to the the list of tours and pass it down to the component

```
function App() {
  const Tours = [
    {
      id: 0,
      image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952",
      title: "title 1",
      price: "$ 1",
      text: "text"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/d32776",
      title: "title 2",
      price: "$ 2",
      text: "description"
    }
  ];

  const [list, setList] = useState(Tours);

  function handleRemove(id) {
    console.log(id);
    const newList = list.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setList(newList);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((value, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={value.id}>
            <Content tour={value} delete={() => handleRemove(index)} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

in the content component, you should pass the **id** of the tour object to the function

```
const Content = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="single-tour">
      <img src={props.tour.image} alt={props.tour.title}></img>
      <div className="container">
        <h4 className="title">{props.tour.title}</h4>
        <h4 className="tour-price">{props.tour.price}</h4>
        <button
          className="delete-btn"
          onClick={() => props.delete(props.tour.id)}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're filtering the array by id which the objects do not have. What you can do is pass an index the filter method:

```
const newList = list.filter((item, i) => i !== index);
```

However, a better practice would be to add an id attribute to the object instead of relying on order.